# Evaluating a real line integral by contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I am evaluating the following integral by using the Residue Theorem:
\begin{eqnarray}
I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx\frac{x}{x^{2}+b^{2}}f(x).
\end{eqnarray}
Assume $f(x)$ is not an even function, for otherwise the integral vanishes. Also, imagine the function $f(x)$ would have simple poles in the complex plane lying exclusively on the imaginary axis, these poles are countable. Then, all poles of the integrand are only within the imaginary axis, and I choose to evaluate the integral using the semi-circle contour in the upper half plane. This means only poles with $\Im(z)>0$ will be enclosed, leaving the poles of the lower-half plane out. Then by using the Residue Theorem, one could evaluate:
\begin{eqnarray}
I=I_{\mathbb{R}}+I_{arc}=2\pi\mathrm{i}\left[\sum_{j}\text{Res}(f(z_{j})) + \frac{1}{2}f(ib) \right],
\end{eqnarray}
where the residues of $f(z)$ are only evaluated for the UHP poles; eventually one takes the radius of the arc $R\to\infty$, so the term $I_{arc}$ does not contribute. Is the above correct to evaluate the integral in a generic fashion? Note we assume $f(z)$ has simple poles, the case of branch-cuts is not considered.

Comment: Make sure you consider the case when $f$ has pole at $ib$. Also, make sure that the integrand vanishes on the arc.

Comment: What would happen if f(ib) is actually a pole? There are two contributions to the residues then, one coming from the pole at $ib$ of $x/(x^2 + b^2)$, the other coming from the pole of $f$ at $ib$? I assumed they would just add up with their corresponding residues.

Comment: The order of the pole is different